# Doubt in Hooke's Law. Coordinate system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, spring

[image]

Hello! I have a question about Hooke's Law.

In the first image, the force experienced by the spring when it is stretched a length $x$ from its equilibrium point $x=0$ is given by $F(x)=-kx$.
In Hooke's Law, $F(x)=-kx$. Should it be understood that the variable $x$ actually refers to the coordinate $x$?

In the second image, the equilibrium point is now at $x=L$ (the length of the spring in its natural state). With this new coordinate system, does the force experienced by the spring when it is stretched a length of $x$ from its equilibrium point $x=L$ also equal $-kx$? Does this mean that $F(L+x)=-kx$? (since at the point $L+x$, the spring experiences such a force).
Finally, what would be the correct work done by the force from point a to point b for the second image? $W_1$ or $W_2$?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplified form of Hooke's law $F(x) = -kx$ only applies to 1D systems where the equilibrium point is at $x=0$. The more general form of Hooke's law in 1D is $F(x) = -k(x-x_{0})$ where $x_{0}$ is the equilibrium position. The latter form is the one that should be used. In your case, $x_{0} = L$.

Your second image is confusing, because when you applied the change of coordinates, you used "$x$" as the coordinate *and* the displacement of the spring at the same time.

I would just say, given the $x$-coordinate from the first image, define a new coordinate by $y = x + L$. Then we have $F(x) = -kx$ in the first coordinate system and $\widetilde{F}(y) = -k(y-L)$ in the second coordinate system.

As functions of coordinates, the functions "$F$" and "$\widetilde{F}$" are technically different functions, but they represent the same force. (This is just like how given a point, the coordinates "$x$" and "$y$" of that point are different numbers but they represent the same point in space.)

To talk about the work done by the spring on the object from point $a$ to point $b$, you have to be careful and specify which coordinates do $a$ and $b$ refer to. Assuming you meant $y=a$ to $y=b$, the work done in the second coordinate system is
$$ W = \int_{y=a}^{y=b} -k(y-L)\,dy. $$
If we change this back to the first coordinate system by $y = x+L$ and $dy=dx$, we get
$$ W = \int_{x=a-L}^{x=b-L} -kx\,dx. $$

Answer (score 2):

Changing the coordinate system does not change the properties of the spring.

Let there be two coordinate systems $x$ and $X$ with $X= x+L$ as defined below.

[image]

The **extension** of the spring from its natural length $L$ is $x$ in one coordinate system and $X-L$ in the other coordinate system.

Thus the force exerted by the spring is $-kx$ in one coordinate system and $-k(X-L)$ in the other coordinate system.

Assuming that the unstretched spring has no elastic potential energy, the elastic potential energy stored in the spring when the extension is $x\,(=X-L)$ is

$\displaystyle \int_0^x k\,x\,dx=\frac 12 k x^2$ or $\displaystyle \int_L^X k\,(X-L)\,dX= \frac12 k (X-L)^2=\frac 12kx^2$